# Join with where query in Laravel returns wrong timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Strange thing happens, I query with the following:

```
$bananafriends   = IsFree::join('friendships', function($join)use($user) {
                    $join->on('arefree.user_id', '=', 'friendships.user_rec_id')
                        ->where('friendships.user_send_id', '=', $user->id); 
                    })
                    ->get();
```

It returns the timestamps & ID of the friendship model but not the isFree model. 
I don't understand why or how I could retrieve the timestamps from the isFree model if that does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the selects are overriding each other.

You need to add a select:

```
$bananafriends = IsFree::join('friendships', function($join)use($user) {
                    $join->on('arefree.user_id', '=', 'friendships.user_rec_id')
                        ->where('friendships.user_send_id', '=', $user->id); 
                    })
                    ->select('friendships.*', 'arefree.*', 'arefree.created_at as free_created')
                    ->get();
```

See the doc on selects:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#selects

If this does not work let me know I will help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks !! Didn't need the last arefree.created_at. Once you select the arefree.* it took the timestamps! Thank you so much  :-)