# Query with inner join returns wrong id

Tags: mysql, laravel

***Update at the end***

I have this API for a social media app in iOS builded in Laravel and i've been having problems with the feed section, the Eloquent code for the feed is giving me the wrong id for each posts.

```
 public function feed(){

        if (request()->has('page')) {

            $pagesize = 20;

            $query = Posts::join('clase_user', function ($join) {

                $user  = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

                $join->on('clase_user.clase_id', '=', 'posts.clase_id')
                    ->where('clase_user.user_id', '=', $user->id);
            })
                ->with('user')
                ->skip(((int)request()->get('page') - 1) * $pagesize)
                ->take($pagesize)->get();

            return $query;
        }else{
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Page not specified'], 500);
        }

    }
```

the return is this:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 1,
            "clase_id": 1,
            "thumbNail": null,
            "text": "Hola Chicos",
            "archivo": null,
            "created_at": "2017-07-20 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-07-20 00:00:00",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Juan Carlos",
                "about": "Hola me llamo Juan Carlos",
                "handler": "Juantvz50",
                "pp": null,
                "verify": 1,
                "email": "jc_estevezr@hotmail.com",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "LoginId": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-20 23:52:28",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-20 23:52:28"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "clase_id": 2,
            "thumbNail": null,
            "text": "Que pex Prrrro",
            "archivo": null,
            "created_at": "2017-07-20 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-07-20 00:00:00",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Juan Carlos",
                "about": "Hola me llamo Juan Carlos",
                "handler": "Juantvz50",
                "pp": null,
                "verify": 1,
                "email": "jc_estevezr@hotmail.com",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "LoginId": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-20 23:52:28",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-20 23:52:28"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 1,
            "clase_id": 1,
            "thumbNail": null,
            "text": "Que Onda Chicos",
            "archivo": null,
            "created_at": "2017-07-20 00:00:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-07-20 00:00:00",
            "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Juan Carlos",
                "about": "Hola me llamo Juan Carlos",
                "handler": "Juantvz50",
                "pp": null,
                "verify": 1,
                "email": "jc_estevezr@hotmail.com",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "LoginId": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-20 23:52:28",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-20 23:52:28"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though my database has different ids for each one:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jywWQ.png)

it looks like something is wrong in some part of my code, I don't know in which part if you want to see more code just ask in the comments.

**UPDATE**

the id it's giving me is in fact the id of the table *clase_user* that is the pivot table I use to join many to many the classes with the users (like when you follow someone on youtube), I think is because i'm saying  *Posts::join('clase_user'*, any ideas to also include the the id of the post?

[*clase_user*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2QKo.png)

Comment: in wich part, I just write ->dd($user->id)? and why, I want to return the post id not the user id, the user id I already have it (btw I updated the post), thanks for the help thought ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to this one: [Join with where query in Laravel returns wrong timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288450/join-with-where-query-in-laravel-returns-wrong-timestamps)

Because of your JOIN the attributes are getting overridden (not only the id but also the created_at/updated_at timestamps). Therefore you should define a select statement for your specific attributes.